# c++ calling ShellExecute without specifying path

Tags: c++, shellexecute

i got a file name that is predefined as a string.
can i call shellexcute without specifying the full path? like:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", PreDefiendFileName, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

what should i do otherwise if not?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Fail gracefully: let the user know that the file could not be found and halt the program.
2. Use a default file that you *know* is there, and inform the user that you are using the default file.

I'd encourage you to think defensively about this problem.  E.g. ensure that the file name that is passed is *actually* a file ("does it have the correct extension?", "does it exist in the file system?") and *then* only call the `ShellExecute` function if those checks pass.

Comment: i know the file is there. i just need to know if i can call the file, let's say : "file.exe" and not call "c:/file.exe"

Comment: Tinker with it.  I suspect that it looks for the file in the directory the program was started from.  If that doesn't work, look at the stack trace and follow the errors until you find your answer.